# Hatched fills in ArcGIS Online

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online

I am building an Web Viewer in ArcGIS online and want to use hatched fills as a style for some polygon layers. However, I cannot figure out how I can do this in ArcGIS Online.

I figured out that you can use hatched fills styles when you upload it through ArcGIS Pro, but ArcGIS Pro is working very slow on my computer and I also want to be able to style webservices from other organisations that I use in my Web Viewer. Is it also possible to create a hatched fill symbology without the use of ArcGIS Pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the ArcGIS Pro work around is the only way how you can get hatched filled symbology in ArcGIS Online. In the following [article](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/hatched-fills-and-how-to-sneak-them-into-arcgis-online/) you can read about it.

I also saw that this feature was requested multiple times on the [ESRI Community](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-ideas/idb-p/arcgis-online-ideas). Here is one from [2012](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-ideas/support-more-robust-symbology-hatching/idi-p/932988) and [2018](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-online-ideas/agol-symbology-hatching/idi-p/935387). Unfortunately, they have not implemented yet, but there may be hope. In the article about sneaking hatched fills in ArcGIS Online (see first link) they wrote that hatch fill should have been implemented in the fall of 2021.

---

ESRI now supports Hatch fills: [What's New in Map Viewer (June 2022)](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/mapping/whats-new-in-map-viewer-june-2022/?rsource=https%3A%2F%2Flinks.esri.com%2Fagol-help%2Fwhats-new-mv-blog)